# Error with pass function from JSON to Knockout component

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm try create a `KnockoutJS component` for paginator

But is occur a problem, where I pass a function in `JSON` to my component params, look like this

```
<paginator params="viewModel: $parent.paginatorViewModel,
                    pagesPerGroup: 5,
                    event: { changePage : $root.perfilViewModel().filtro.filtrar}"></paginator>
```

Where `$root.perfilViewModel()` is a `ko.observable()`

```
perfilViewModel = ko.observable(new myViewModel());
```

And `$root.perfilViewModel().filtro` is another `View Model`

```
filtro = new filterViewModel();

function filterViewModel() {
     this.filtrar = function(){
          //my filter code here
     }
}
```

And in my component, I'm get properties with fallowing code:

```
if (params.event)
{
    for (var k in params.event)
    {
        var event = params.event[k];

        // another code here
    }
}
```

Why in `params.event` is returning for me:

```
function g(){if(0<arguments.length){if("function"===typeof C)C.apply(d,arguments);else throw Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the c…
```

If I execute this function (in chrome debug console), it return for me object what I wanted.

After many test, I discovered, this problem occur when my `perfilViewModel` is an `observable`, where it is a `new myViewModel()` normal, I can receive `event` property normal

Why occur this situation? how to can I pass function in `JSON` to component, if I need my `View Model` is result of an `observable`?

Comment: the error states you are trying to assign some value to computed observable which can be only done if you use `write` function internally . can you make a fiddle with complete code

Comment: I don't think it's legitimate to pass `viewModel` as part of `params`, is it?

Comment: Please, show the relevant code of your paginator component. If not, it's impossible to guess what is the problem and give a solution.

Comment: I will create this in `jsFiddle` later, sorry for the delay